# svn revert on same branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My development branch[dev] was all set to release but somehow few features need to be reverted.
My branch head is pointing to revision 7627.
Below are the steps which I am following to revert the features.
1. I have taken checkout of the last release revision[7611].
2. And have merged required features in my local working copy from different revision commits. i.e. revision 7622 partially(a,b,c,d file changes I took only a and b where c and d files are new files), 7623,7625 complete merges.
3. Now I am trying to commit the working copy. while committing tortoise svn is showing files to commit in the dialog box. Where the files changed by me are listed but not the one which was already there in HEAD(e.g c and d which I don't want to be there in HEAD) and needs to be deleted.
4. If I go ahead and commit, will c and d get deleted from HEAD?
As this is master branch I want to be a bit careful before committing.
Hope this is making some sense.

Comment: IMHO this is not clear. Please explain step by step what you did with correct indentation and punctuation. Then explain what you expect and what you observe.

Comment: I have updated the question hope it is bit clear now. Revert if u need any more inputs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have in mind that SVN always goes ahead in revisions; I mean that SVN will always require that your working copy is updated to HEAD revision before any commit. So what you tried seems wrong, and I suggest you two solutions:

1. Create a new branch from revision 7611:

   - then perform the local merge of revisions 7622 (partially),7623,7625 into this branch.
   - finally commit into this new branch, which becomes your development branch.
2. OR keep your current branch:

   - perform a check-out of the HEAD revision
   - then perform a local **reversed** merge of revisions 7612-7621,7624,7626,7627: with `TortoiseSVN`, check the box `Reverse merge` after selecting the revisions
   - you can also perform other local modifications as deleting c and d files, as said in your post
   - finally commit.